PowerBI dashboard dynamically displaying administrative level 1 regions in ArcGIS visual
In PowerBI I am trying to create a monthly forecast dashboard that displays on a world map for a given month [using a slider] which administrative level 1 regions would be affected by tropical storms (TCs). To determine which region would be affected at a given time I use open source data from NOAA on historic TCs with per month the frequency of TCs for each TC basin (using  6 different basins in total), which I structured as follows:



Month
Region
Frequency
Month number




January
I. North Atlantic
0
1


January
II. Eastern and Central North Pacific
15
1


January
III. North Indian
33
1



(More extended example)
I assign a color code to each TC-vulnerable administrative level 1 region based on the statistical frequency of TC occurrence in a given month (e.g., red for > 80, orange for 50-80 etc.)
The vulnerable admin level 1 regions are identified per basin (based on a record of the last 30-50 years) and included in a seperate table. This is structured as follows:
Table with admin 1 levels per basin
I use the ArcGIS map visual to display the data as it allows to also display additional layers on top (such as historic TC trajectories). For displaying the data on a country level, this is very easily done by adding the country names affected per basin in the Location field and the corresponding frequency per basin in the Color field, as shown below (incl. the additional TC trajectory layer)
Example dashboard with countries (admin level 0) instead of districts/provinces (admin level 1)
However, I prefer more detail than the just displaying this on a country level (administrative level 0), but unfortunately the ArcGIS visual does not support the projection of administrative level 1 data on global scale via the Location Field - requiring me to find a work-around.
I decided upon using different shapefiles with all administrative level 1 regions in the world, with different colours based on the above color assignment (frequency of occurrence categories).
As a proof of concept I tried it with two colours: one in red (>=50) and one in green (<50). My goal is to project all administrative level 1 regions of the red shapefile corresponding to the basins that have a frequency of occurrence of TC for a given month >= 50, and similarly for green, being displayed for frequencies <50.
an example as a proof of concept
It requires to have a separate table for each color category and then make a Join Layer connection with the admin_1 column of the shapefile.
Image example: Cumbersome way to link data to ArcGIS visual (via Join Layer Field)
I can imagine there must be a much more efficient way to do this. Would anyone be able to suggest a better way to do this?
